# Streaming a wmv file with mms protocol in Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, video-streaming, rtsp

I am attempting to stream lectures via the MMS protocol (`mms://xxxx/xxx/xxx.wmv`) in Windows and Linux Mint 11. In Windows, this is no problem using Windows Media Player. In Linux, however, I have to change the protocol in VLC's *network stream* tab to RTSP.

The problem is:

I can't speed up the playback (ie. 1.5x, I have to save time).
The time bar doesn't work, so you can't tell how far into a lecture you are or how much time is left.

How can I stream videos over MMS in Linux while preserving the ability to change playback speed and view playback progress?

Comment: so i guess this isn't an easy problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Using VLC 1.1.11 you should be able to see the time elapsed and total time remaining in your stream. I am not sure about speed but you should be able to fast forward.
`vlc -I rc rtsp://xxxx/xxx/xxx.wmv` or `vlc -I rc mms://xxxx/xxx/xxx.wmv` is the correct format. Please note that mms is just a protocol rollover as its been deprecated in favour of rtsp.

Comment: the time bar now works fine , but fast forwarding not , and : "mms is just a protocol rollover as its been deprecated in favour of rtsp" this is what bugs me , why it would work in windows media player and not vlc.

Comment: While streaming mms in VLC you can click anywhere in the time bar to seek to that position. Try this `vlc mmsh://xxx/xxx.wmv` [MMSH](http://wiki.videolan.org/MMSH) will stream MMS over HTTP

Comment: no it still doesn't work , only vlc rtsp://XXXX/Xxx.wmv works , but also without the possibility of fast forwarding ...